# How can I make another request within catchError?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

```
  this.service.login().pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse, responseObservable: Observable<boolean>) => {
        if (error.status === 400) {
          return this.service.doSomethingElse.pipe(map(() => throwError(error)));
        } else {
          return throwError(error);
        }
      }),
    ).subscribe(
```

The response from this is always a 200, It won't throw the error when the status code is 400 and return from making the other request.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Could you add `console.log(error.status)` in cathcError `firstline`(Before if clause),and share output wiht us?

Comment: it prints out 400

Comment: if `400` is `string` try `==` instead of `===`

Comment: You could use `retryWhen` pipe

Answer (score 3):

With `map()` you map values from `this.service.doSomethingElse` Observable to `throwError(error)` Observable, so you get stream of streams.

You should flatten it with `mergeMap` or other flattening operator. Like:

```
return this.service.doSomethingElse.pipe(mergeMap(() => throwError(error)));
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. I have been at this for good few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.service.login()
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
     }, error => {
       if (error.status === 400) {
          return this.service.doSomethingElse.pipe(map(() => throwError(error)));
       } else {
           return throwError(error);
       }
 })
```

Comment: I would rather pipe the two requests into one, and not have nested requests.